# jquery div positioning only when scroll up

Tags: jquery, html, positioning

I have this jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ns44/5/

The idea is to open an expanded view of a div always in the view port. This works fine. And I want to stick to this method (NO fixed position divs).
But when the window is scrolled, I would like the expand window to move up as user scrolls up, but it SHOULD not scroll down if user scrolls down.

In the fiddle, if the user scrolls down after scrolling up, the expand div will scroll down until where it was originally opened.

Can anyone throw some light into `margin-top` and positioning on scroll?

Comment: Thank you for making a clear minimized example in jsfiddle!  So many times people paste in huge code globs that are hard to get to the bottom of.  +1 just for that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/4Ns44/6/

It updates the `expandY` variable everytime you scroll and doesn't let it move down the page from where it was previously.

One thing to keep in mind:  You should use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the link from being followed instead of `return false`.  `preventDefault()` will still allow other events to fire, while `return false` will stop event execution in it's tracks.  It can cause confusion if you were to add other click handlers etc.